# Super lop-sided CSS column distribution in Chrome and IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, google-chrome

I have a simple two column design using the CSS `column` properties, with unequally sized blocks of content, where I don't want any block to be broken over two columns. This basically works, but for some reason, in Chrome, and to a lesser extent in IE, the column break is placed at the wrong spot with certain combinations of content blocks.

Example HTML:

```
<div class="twocolumn">
    <div style="height:200px;"></div>
    <div style="height:500px;"></div>
    <div style="height:100px;"></div>
    <div style="height:100px;"></div>
    <div style="height:100px;"></div>
    <div style="height:100px;"></div>
    <div style="height:200px;"></div>
</div>
```

Example CSS:

```
.twocolumn{
    -moz-column-count:2;
    -webkit-column-count:2;
    column-count:2;

    -moz-column-gap:12px;
    -webkit-column-gap:12px;
    column-gap:12px;
}

.twocolumn div{
    margin-bottom:2px;
    background-color:red;
    width:100%;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

And [as a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DashielN/ct2Xh/1/) for easy tinkering.

Compare that example in various browsers and you'll see that in Firefox the columns are split as evenly as possible by height, where as in IE an extra item shifts from the second to the first column, and in Chrome *two* items scoot over there.

Anyone see something I'm doing wrong here, or know a work-around?

Comment: I've seen worse column distribution on Chrome with the first of 3 columns getting two elements while the 3rd has none. [And there are other issues with css3 columns.](http://zomigi.com/blog/deal-breaker-problems-with-css3-multi-columns/) We'll have to live with these limitations until the browsers improve.